# R restructuring long to wide using for loop

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

Right now, this working loop is pasting the supervisor's scores for a given year into new columns (`supervisor.score1`:`supervisor.score4`) on the appropriate employee row. It achieves this by looking at an employee row i and finding the employee row(s) for the supervisor and year listed in row i. Then it takes the first row on that list of matching rows, and pastes the scores (`score1`:`score 4`) from that row into `supervisor.score1`:`supervisor.score4` for the corresponding employee row i.

`employeeID` `year` `supervisor` `score1`:`score 4` `supervisor.score1`:`supervisor.score4`

```
for (i in (1:nrow(data))){
  matchvector <- which(data[,1] == data[i,3] & data[,2] == data[i,2])
  if (length(matchvector) > 0) {
    case <- matchvector[1]
    data[i, namevector] <- data[case, supervisor.score1:supervisor.score4]}
  if (length(matchvector[1]) < 1){
    data[i, supervisor.score1:supervisor.score4] <- NA}
}
```

Is there a way to convert this loop into a function that can be called with apply?

Comment: Please share a few lines of data using `dput()` to turn this into a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Also please be a little clearer - what are you hoping to `apply` this over? A list of data frames? Something else? What needs to be parameterized in the function (i.e., what is different in each application)? Or do you want to replace the `for` loop with `apply`?